# that" in a second clause

Tags: complementation

Are the following sentences all okay? Any stylistic preference?

> a. The ex-con told his wife he would be away for a long time and **that** she could just forget about him.

> b. The ex-con told his wife **that** he would be away for a long time and **that** she could just forget about him.

> c. The ex-con told his wife **that** he would be away for a long time and she could just forget about him.

> d. The ex-con told his wife he would be away for a long time and she could just forget about him.

Comment: They're all syntactically "valid". Personally, I think it's a bit clumsy to omit the *first* possible instance of relativiser ***that** [he would be away]* but then to include the *second* possibility ***that** [she could forget him]*. But that's just my opinion on a matter of ***writing style***, not necessarily shared by others.

Comment: Side notes: Are there three people involved here? Because of "her wife", it reads like  one partner in a female same-sex marriage is telling the other partner that some male would be away for a long time. I'm guessing that's not the intent. Did you mean, "his wife"? Also, this sounds more like something a new convict would say, not an ex-con.